# Is this config is capable to import complete osm planet file?

Tags: openstreetmap

We have a server with this config :

Processor: E5-2609 v2
RAM: 16GB 1333MHz
HDD: 2TB 7200rpm

and we want to import complete osm planet file to postgreSQL database.
Is that possible with this config or we need more powerfull system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system requirements are listed on [switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). Your system seems to be okay but it will take a while importing the whole planet. Don't expect it to finish during a single day.